# Find a Value From Array of NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a `NSArray` containing multiple `NSDictionary` object and this NSDictionary again has one array of some `NSStrings/NSNumbers`...

This `NSArray` looks like below...

```
(
        {
        "bins_arr" =         (
            531662,
            549177,
            540165,
            546616,
            549777,
            549778,
            549779,
            532663,
            549852,
            529495,
            532662,
            529117,
            533890,
            544170,
            554619,
            542418,
            540175,
            552137,
            542531,
            542556,
            552093,
            540531,
            552790,
            541497,
            554637,
            526421,
            431921,
            412800,
            431922,
            464558,
            508159,
            456822,
            450900,
            508126,
            508125,
            517700,
            430463,
            414746,
            461797,
            438628,
            461796,
            510460,
            520386,
            421175,
            455038,
            524133,
            518936,
            455390,
            405450,
            456407,
            438587,
            405451,
            493714,
            549149
        );
        "issuing_School" = ABCDEF;
        status = 0;
        title = ABCDEF;
    },
        {
        "bins_arr" =         (
            429393,
            416644,
            416645,
            416643,
            416646,
            436390,
            436389,
            436388,
            470613,
            524253,
            428306,
            489604,
            478893,
            414767,
            428348,
            469645,
            421493,
            470614,
            543705
        );
        "issuing_School" = PQRS;
        status = 0;
        title = "PQRS";
    },
        {
        "bins_arr" =         (
            422316,
            421560,
            483541
        );
        "issuing_School" = TCSB;
        status = 0;
        title = "TCSB";
    }
)
```

Now I need to find out a given `NString/NSNumber` inside the `NSArray`, if it gets found I need to fine corresponding `issuing_School` value as well, for example If I find **461797** so it should search it and find that issuing_School of this is **PQRS**.

One way of doing it is to get the each `NSArray` inside `NSArray`-->`NSDictionary` and loop through the whole `NSArray` and match the given number with the number present and in the `NSArray`, but I don't want this search since this `NSArray` have so may object of `NSDictionary` and all `NSDictionary` object again have big `NSArray`.

Can Any one suggest me some awesome view to achieve this. 
**Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: You don't have to use a loop yourself (for the array of numbers) you can use containsObject to look for a particular number (though that method probably uses a loop internally).

Comment: yes I could use containsObject but ultimately I end up with looping only since containsObject does use loops. btw thanks @rdelmar

Comment: There's no way to go through an array that doesn't involve a loop either explicitly or implicitly (except for using a predicate maybe -- I'm not sure how that's implemented, and it's usually slower than a loop anyway).

Comment: Unless your inner array is sorted in some logical way you can't really search it without a loop. And they don't look sorted.

Comment: guys what about trie data structure ???? I have little knowledge of it and I think it solve my purpose but I'm not pretty much sure.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your arrays into sets.

```
NSArray* array = ...;
NSSet* set = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:array];

if ([set containsObject:aNumber]) ...
```

No loop involved. Constant time no matter how many elements in the set.

Comment: Only constant time *after* the sets are created.